# get the transactions of previous month regardless the day and time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wondering if there is more efficient way to get the following scenario.
check the datasets

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e18a8c1200c8eac1f3bdca184075358e

I need to get the data of previous month using getdate function as a base line regardless the day.
any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient method is direct date comparisons:

```
where trandate < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      trandate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

This allows the optimizer to use indexes and partitions that are based on `trandate`.  Also, the statistics are more accurate for `trandate` directly -- and functions impede the use of statistics.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gorden,  I didn't get why function impede use of statistics?

Comment: @Nawaf . . . That is an interesting question, actually.  Statistics are maintained on the raw values of the data.  It would certainly be possibly to use indexes for some functions, however, it is very hard to generalize across *all* functions (or even function classes).  So optimizers tend to "ignore" functions (well, actually they just make generic assumptions not based on statistics).

Answer (score 0):

```
-- using datediff
select * from aaa
where datediff(MONTH,aaa.trandate,getdate()) = 1
```